# Newbie one: Virtual Networks - Hyper-V - Remote Destktop - Only one physical NIC

Tags: windows-server-2008, virtualization, hyper-v-server-2008-r2

I'll try to explain my situation and I'll apreciate any help:

I have a phisical server (quad core, 4Gb ram, 1TB raid 10, etc) with Win Server 2008 R2 enterprise, running IIS, Printing, etc...

Also, I want to set up 2 virtual Servers with 2008 R2 standart one with SQL Server and the other with Team Foundation.

What i need is:

1. Being able to access from inside the private phisical network, to Remote Desktops on each of the Virtual and the phisical Servers
2. Had Access from the outside, using a router and port Forwarding, to the TFS server and the IIS server (one is virtualized, the other is phisical)

This is it, but note that I only have one Phisical Nic. How do I configure this to work. When i set up the hyper-v role, on the wizard something like it showed up but I don't remmember what i choose, and right now, I cannot access none of the servers from remote desktop, not even from the phisical private network.

Can anybody point me, what can i do? Thanks in advance

(sorry 4 my english, i'm a spanish talker and my english isn't that good)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used Hyper-V, so I'm basing this answer on other hypervisors.

When you create & configure a VM, it usually gives you the option to add a virtual NIC card. Usually, there will be several ways to configure this NIC, and how it interfaces with the physical NIC. The 2 most common options are "bridged networking" and "NAT".

"Bridged networking" bridges your virtual NIC to your physical NIC, and will make the virtual NIC act like a machine on the same subnet as the host machine. "NAT" configures your virtual NIC to use network address translation, and make it look as though it is sitting on a different subnet, behind a virtual router.

From your description, my guess is that your VMs are configured to use NAT, so they don't appear on your host subnet. For you to access them this way, you would need to configure routing between the 2 networks. If this is what you desire, you'll need to figure it out in Hyper-V, configure one of the virtual servers as a router/gateway, or create a virtual router with something like Vyatta.

However, if this is *not* what you want, then the simplest solution is to change the VM NICs to use bridged networking. If there is no option to change it, add a new NIC with bridged, and delete the old one.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your exact requirements. But anyway you should log on to HYPER-V manager and check Virtual Network Manager. I guess you didn't install Core version without GUI?
Here you can see all your Virtual Networks and whether they are private(VMs only), internal(VMs plus host) or external(VMs plus host plus LAN through physical NIC).
Then check your VM, which Virtual Network is it's Virtual NIC connected to. It's really easy. If in doubt click "Help"(at the right bottom corner).
Hope it helps